# Change ownership and permissions of file

Tags: linux, permissions, bash, chmod

Is it possible to change owner/group of a file AND permissions with 1 command?
I tried:
`chmod user1:groupOfUser1=770 file.txt`
but it does not work.

Comment: Make a shell script that combines the `chmod` and `chown` commands?

Comment: @DerfK Indeed. Or alias. Or a Bash function.

Comment: My thoughts are that the answer might be in some the usage of [setfacl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl).  Is it possible to update owner/group and default permissions with setfcacl?

Answer (score 4):

Create a script

Similar to this you can modify as per your need

```
cat chmodown
#!/bin/bash

chmod $2 $1 $5
chown $3:$4 $1 $5
```

$1 is file name $2 is permission $3 user name  $4 Group name $5 (-R) for recursive.

You can then place the same script to "/usr/bin/" too.

```
chmodown install.log 777 test root
ls -al install.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 test root 18262 Jul 27 01:52 install.log
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's really possible.

I expect that what you are looking for is to input file name just once. You can do something like this

# for a in file.txt; do chown  user1:groupOfUser1 $a; chmod 770 $a; done

Over here you need to input the file name just once :)

At the same time, you can use shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
chown $1:$2 $4
chmod $3 $4
```

Make this executable and put it in your PATH variable and use it something like this.

# ./x.sh user group permission file_name